# how to track traffic source for a Facebook iframe application

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, referrer

I have a facebook iframe application - let's call it apps.facebook.com/my-app.

We currently use Google Analytics for our tracking, and I correctly have Google Analytics installed on my application (that is included via iframe to the FB app) & it is tracking any use of the application mentioned above.

However, I would like to find out what the traffic source is to my-app PRIOR to facebook; ie, if a user goes to domain1.com, and follows a link from there to apps.facebook.com/my-app, it appears that the "traffic source" gets tracked as "apps.facebook.com" rather than "domain1.com", b/c the GA is installed within my code of the page included via the iframe, so its http referer is apps.facebook.com

Is there any way to retrieve "domain1.com" as my traffic source, in this case?  Or any suggestions to try? (whether using Google Analytics, or another source? I see that the facebook insights does give some information on referrers, but it's not very extensive at all; no date ranges, etc)

Thanks so much!
- ali

Answer (score 0):

Just using Google Analytics in Facebook, there isn't much you can do here.  However, what we've done in the past (to general success) is to create a redirect link *outside* of Facebook with the analytics on it, and push all traffic there first.

In other words, create a page at www.myapp.com/redirect, and put the google tracker there (or, alternately, just append the referrer url to the query string manually).  Then, redirect with javascript out to the Facebook canvas app URL.  That way, the user ends up in the right place, and you get your referrer info as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.So, are users interfacing first with www.myapp.com/redirect, rather than going directly to the actual facebook app? (ie, is the actual link you provide to users going to www.myapp.com/redirect, or to apps.facebook.com/my-app)

Comment: The former — you'd do www.myapp.com/redirect, and then off to apps.facebook.com/my-app after.